# Stuck At Almost Finished Copying Files

Tags: system-installation, wubi

To install Ubuntu I used the windows installer, and after reboot I'm stuck at "almost finished copying files...".

Have been here for 20 minutes. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

It's not normal, but there have been a small number of reports of it lately. There could be causes such as graphics hangs in which case you could boot with `nomodeset` and see whether it makes a difference.

Or capture the logs and attach them to a [new bug report](http://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+filebug).  to get to a terminal when it's stuck, and run:

```
sudo zip -r /host/ubuntu/logs.zip /var/log
```

Then you can return to the installer GUI  or just reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Your logs can then be found under windows as `C:\ubuntu\logs.zip` (assuming you installed on the `C:` drive).

In your bug report you can mention your full computer specs (brand/model/graphics card) and the release of Ubuntu you are installing.